# How to execute a HTML file on my homepage?

Tags: html

I just created a basic html file and want to upload that file to my website.

So what I've done is, went to cpanel->file manager->/htdocs and uploaded the file(**sandy.html**).

But the problem is it's not executing on my home page( i.e. sandeep.0fees.net). It's just showing the file that I uploaded.

I think you'll understand better when you see [my website.](http://sandeep.0fees.net/)

Where I'm going wrong? What should I do to make that file to run on *sandeep.0fees.net* instead of *sandeep.0fees.net/sandy.html*?

Answer (score 3):

Rename your file to `index.html`

Or call it directly http://sandeep.0fees.net/sandy.html

Answer (score 3):

Try renaming it index.html.  There is a setting called a default document and that is the file that is loaded when you end the url without a filename.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be the default landing page, call it *index.html* instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this line to the **.htaccess** file, in the **public_html** folder:

```
DirectoryIndex sandy.html index.php index.html
```

If it doesn't exist, create it! :)